# Trying to run Django app on App Engine flex, getting Server 502 when accessing handler

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework

I'm building a simple login page. You can log in using a Django account, or using Google Sign-In. I am trying to verify that you can log in using a Django account first.

It deploys correctly, and I can access the site properly.

But when I access Django `/admin` and key in the login credentials, aside from the fact that loading takes forever, I keep getting `Server 502 Bad Gateway`

The documentations only [vaguely mentions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app) all the way at the bottom that app.yaml might be configured incorrectly but I'm not experienced enough to tell which part isnt.

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT [myproject.wsgi]
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: [instance]:asia-east2:[project]

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
# [END runtime]
```

Relevant Error Log:

```
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /admin/" 302
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/" 200
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css" 404
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css" 404
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /static/admin/css/login.css" 404
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /static/admin/css/base.css" 404
2021-08-19 20:12:44 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js" 404
2021-08-19 20:13:24 default[20210820t040009]  [2021-08-19 20:13:24 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:13)
2021-08-19 20:13:24 default[20210820t040009]  [2021-08-19 20:13:24 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
2021-08-19 20:13:24 default[20210820t040009]  [2021-08-19 20:13:24 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
2021-08-19 20:13:24 default[20210820t040009]  "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/" 502
2021-08-19 20:13:43 default[20210820t040009]  "GET /nginx_metrics" 200
```

Comment: Please include the app's logs in your question: `gcloud app logs` is one way to grab these.

Comment: `502`s result for many reasons including misconfiguration (your `app.yaml` looks fine). Does your app run correctly locally? Your question suggests that the `/admin` handler does initially respond and it's only when you submit the request that the error occurs, correct?

Comment: Seems like it, yes. I can access ```/admin``` and view a page with a form to allow submission, but when I click on the login button, I get a 520 error

Comment: Here's the error `POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/" 502`

Comment: I'm.....not seeing the problem?

Comment: Since you're getting a `502`, it suggests your code is finding the handler but the handler is failing

Comment: Have you tried using --no-cache on your gcloud app deploy command? If not, kindly do so to eliminate the possibility of caching issue. See this documentation for reference https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: @MabelA. Tried. Got ```INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unrecognized or unpermitted key(s) in configuration "beta_settings"
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Unrecognized beta_setting key
    field: no-cache```

Comment: @DazWilkin any suggestions on how do I go about handling it?

Comment: There are many ways you can test the handler. The easiest is probably to use `curl`. If you're posting an HTML FORM to the handler, then you'd use `curl --request POST --form [field1]=[value1] --form [field2]=[value2] ... [service-endpoint]` replacing everything in `[...]` with actual values. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why. But I had to change details in my `settings.py`

I asked someone I knew who did a deployment to Google Cloud previously for reference.
After checking out the difference, the main thing was how the `HOST` was setup with regards to the DATABASE.

What I did was this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '[DATABASE NAME]',
        'HOST': '[IP Address based on Public IP on the Google Cloud SQL Instance]',  
        'USER': '[SQL USER]', # Cloud
        'PASSWORD': '[SQL PASSWORD]', # Cloud
    }
}
```

What they did was this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '[DATABASE NAME]',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/[instance]:asia-east2:[project]',
        'USER': '[SQL USER]', # Cloud
        'PASSWORD': '[SQL PASSWORD]', # Cloud
    }
}
```

The closest reference I could find in the document was [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible#connecting_to), specifically under  `Connect with Unix sockets`

> Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the environment's filesystem at the following path: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME.

The instant I made the change and deployed, I could successfully access my Django backends.

Answer (score -1):

This error usually means that the server was not able to proxy the request. There are a lot of possible problems to this so a good starting spot would be to execute this command to open up the error log and troubleshoot.

sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log